# How to modify the runQueryOnBackgroundThread in order to identify where Activity I came from?

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have three tabbed activities and everyone is a listView with the same cursorAdapter.
Of course, there is a different cursor in every activity (the only difference between them is the `where` string).

I have overridden the `runQueryOnBackgroundThread()` in the adapter in order to have a filtered list.

I need to know the Actvity I came from when I am inside the `runQueryOnBackgroundThread()` method, because I need to  add a string to the `filtered` query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `.getClass().getSimpleName();`

Comment: Thanks, but this only return the name of the Adapter. The problem is every Activity is using the same Adapater, and I need the name of the calling Activity.

Comment: Then pass the Activity to the Adapter?

Comment: Yes! You are right! Pass the context, then I can use your .getClass().getSimpleName() suggestion! ;) Thanks Tim!